# Request Timeout Error In InfluxDB in node in nodered

Tags: node-red, influxdb-2, request-timed-out

I recognized that requesting to influxdb from nodered with approximately more than 10s long query resulted in RequestTimedOutError: Request timed out.

The problem is that my request to influxb from nodered takes pretty much times. I was wondering is there any other way I can increase timeout or is there any alternative way to wait that query without getting timeout error and get the result from influxdb instead.

Comment: Edit the question to show which Node-RED node you are using. But there is this https://community.influxdata.com/t/lost-metrics-due-to-requesttimedouterror/18893/5